# Only My textarea of Contact-form does not responsiove even after using col-md class.help me to solve

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this all input textbox is responsive for mobile.
    But input textarea doesnot responsive in mobile which is displayed in screenshot

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    
                            <span style="margin-right:5px; ">Message</span>
                                <textarea class="form-control form-inline"  id="Message" cols="15" name="message" rows="4"style="width: 1000px"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                        <div class="row" align="center">
                             <button type="submit" class="btn contact-btn">SUBMIT</button>
                        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: i'm added an answer if which helps don't forget to tick it.

Answer (score 0):

Change Textarea html code to this

```
<textarea class="form-control"  id="Message" name="message" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because of
style="width: 1000px"
set it
style="width: 90%" for example and it will be responsive also

Comment: i had also tried with width:100% bt not work then after i use 1000px size bcz when its  desktop size i must require msgbox  with 1000px width textarea

Comment: try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vypbdY ,for desktop size  you have amsgbox with exactly 1000px, and other devices and resolution you will have 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Remove class .form-inline & hard coded width keep it simple it works fine

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="message">message</label>
       <textarea
           class="form-control" 
           id="message" 
           placeholder="message">
       </textarea>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this.

Only changes this `style="width: 1000px;"` to `style="width: 100%;"`

```
<textarea class="form-control form-inline"  id="Message" cols="15" name="message" rows="4" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happened because you write the property value of width in pixel.the maximum mob screen width is 768 pixel.so replace it with percentage value.(ie,put style="**width: 100%**" instead of style="width: 1000px")

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    
                            <span style="margin-right:5px; ">Message</span>
                                <textarea class="form-control form-inline"  id="Message" cols="15" name="message" rows="4"style="width: 100%"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                        <div class="row" align="center">
                             <button type="submit" class="btn contact-btn">SUBMIT</button>
                        </div>
```

Comment: i had also tried with width:100% bt not work then after i use 1000px size bcz when its  desktop size i must require msgbox  with 1000px width textarea

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are giving the explicit `width: 1000px` to the textarea remove that code and everything will work fine.

If you want give width `1000px` on desktop then use media query for large screen only. and give width `1000px` in that media query instead of inline.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <span style="margin-right:5px; ">Message</span>
         <textarea class="form-control form-inline"  id="Message" cols="15" name="message" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" align="center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn contact-btn">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```